# SharePoint Online change the Collapsible section header font size

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Recently SharePoint released the Collapsible section for SharePoint online, however it's impossible to change the font size from the available setting. From this URL looks like a lot of people complaining but nobody got an answer. It looks ugly with a huge header. Does anybody know how to adjust it? Maybe via PowerShell or inject CSS to replace it?

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-collapsible-sections-on-modern-pages/m-p/2510198/page/3

[image: The header is too big]
The header text is too big.

[image]
The CSS found with Chrome developer tool. Sometimes it's -87, sometimes it's -88.

I had tried to replace the CSS in the "Style Library", but still the same. Anybody got a clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS style in a modern script editor WP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).